# Control selenium nodes individually

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, networking, selenium-grid

I am working on building an automated test suite based on selenium where I can spawn bots that I can control and use to test my webapp. Doing this itself is trivial, however, I want to spawn the selenium nodes such that their network conditions can be controlled by 'tc' linux command, as I want full control of the network conditions of the bots. Selenium's own network configuration options aren't enough, and so I have made a docker image with a small python script along with the selenium node, which controls the network config and exposes a rpc port which i can use to control the network configurations remotely.

The problem is, the dockers would be scaled by lets say an auto scalar, and lets say I know the ip addresses and port mappings of all the hosts. But the webdriver would only connect to the hub and whenever i make a new Builder, the hub would load balance itself and provide a random node to me, and I won't know its host ip and port mappings. The ips are all private as all of this is in a vpc.
So basically all i want is to be able to have webdriver directly control selenium nodes, and to not have any hub in between at all, and for me to do all the load balancing etc myself so I can have full knowledge of what browser is from what node and so I can connect and control its network.

I researched a bit but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help? Just to bypass the hub and connect and use selenium web driver apis directly on the node. Thanks.

Now I have a system and whenever I need a bot, I spawn selenium containers individually at a time, wait for them to connect to the hub, and then use its browser (1 chrome per node) instantly, so I am assured of what bot has what ip/port mappings. But this isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with selenium standalone grid ?
you can achieve the same , here you need to handle port numbers individually.
you can spawn as many container .

```html
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.4.0-20220812
$ docker run -d -p 4445:4444 -p 5901:5900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-edge:4.4.0-20220812
$ docker run -d -p 4446:4444 -p 5902:5900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-firefox:4.4.0-20220812
```